# Примести текст для mxl

Tags: php, xml

В заголовках и описании, встречаются различные символы на которые гугл и яндекс ругается.

К примеру для sitemap, гугл ругается на подобные символы '&'

Вопрос в том, быть может кто сталкивался и есть готовое выражение для регулярки. Которое исключит различные символы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю что речь идет о том чтобы заменить символ **&** на код **`&amp;`**

Для этого не нужны регулярные выражения. Можно это сделать как с помощью обычной замены, так и с помощью специальных функций.

В PHP, например, для этого есть функция [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php)